# How to establish ssh connection to postgresql via Java?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, ssh

I'm trying to connect to my postgresql Database using Java and jdbc but I need to create an ssh tunnel connexion first! can someone help me Please? Do I need to write a programme with Java to create the ssh connection I really don't know how to proceed! I get this error.

org. postgresql. util. PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba. coin entry for a host

Comment: You can create the SSH tunnel using e.g. through a putty session

Comment: Or use forticlient.

Comment: i've established my connection throught putty but the same error is still presisting